# grails 4 - BindingFormat annotation not binding date when using code for localized binding

Tags: grails, data-binding, grails-4

As per the [docs](https://docs.grails.org/4.0.2/guide/single.html#_localized_binding_formats), we can use localized data binding. But this is not working in grails 4.

**controller**

```
import grails.databinding.BindingFormat

class TestController {

  def index() {
    render view: 'index'
  }

  def test(DateCommand command) {
    render "${params} <br/><br/> - ${command.errors?.collect { error -> error as String }?.join(', ')}"
  }
}

class DateCommand {

  @BindingFormat(code = 'date.field.format')
  Date aDate
  @BindingFormat('dd/MM/yyyy')
  Date bDate

  static constraints = {
    aDate(nullable: false)
    bDate(nullable: false)
  }
}
```

**index view**

```
<g:form action="test">
  <input type="text" name="aDate" value="27/04/2019" />
  <input type="text" name="bDate" value="27/04/2019" />
  <g:submitButton class="btn btn-success" name="OK" />
</g:form>
```

**messages.properties**

```
date.field.format=dd/MM/yyyy
```

Same code is working fine in grails 3.x.x

Am I missing some configuration or something is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing some configuration or something is wrong in the code?

It looks like the annotation handling may be broken for that.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues we can get it straightened out.

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround --

```
command.aDate = params.date('aDate', message(code: 'date.field.format'))
command.clearErrors()
command.validate()
```

and implements CO with grails.validation.Validateable trait.